# Is the usage of "over" in the meaning of "finished" formal?

Tags: formal-language

Is the usage of "over" in the meaning of "finish" like the below sentence formal?

> My project will be over by 2022.

Comment: Very unusual. I'd say "... will be completed by ... " instead.

Answer (score 2):

To say that something is over means that is has ended. For example, "When the movie is over, I will leave the cinema." It is not particularly formal. However, in your instance, if you are not saying that the duration of your project has elapse (like the the movie which has come to an end), but rather that you have accomplished what you set out to do, I would say "My project will be completed ..."

Comment: _Over_ is mainly used of things we can't control (like a shower of rain) or that have a fixed duration (like a film).